# Swapping a self-signed cert for a trusted cert?

Tags: java, ssl

I have a server that uses a self-signed certificate to serve https connections to my test clients.

My client app is written in java, and I was having it accept the self-signed cert like so:

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

SSLSocketFactory factory = new SSLSocketFactory(myTrustedStore);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry()
    .register(new Scheme("https", factory, 456));
```

Now I have a proper ssl certificate from a trusted third party provider.

If I swap certificates, will the connection above fail? Because I'm explicitly initializing with the SSLSocketFactory above, will the client reject the server certificate (which would be a real trusted one?).

Just wondering if I have to change the code above and have my testers update their client apps, or, will the connection just work transparently without them having to update?

Thanks

----- Follow up ------

I've tried with the 'real' certificate. The code I had to use the self-signed cert would not work. So I had to drop the code above in my clients before they'd work with the real cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client has accepted a self-signed cert, there will be no problem to use a properly validable trusted cert.

If there are problems, you can still import the new cert manually into your trustedStore. Your code should not be effected.

Comment: Hi yeah same question - so the client code doesn't need to be modified then? It'll accept the new trusted cert, even though I'm initializing the connection with the explicit self-signed cert?

Comment: **"Your code should not be effected."** - No, your code is OK. You may have to import the new cert, if it fails, but - since you will need this code for staging - you should not change it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that now you have a proper certificate you can remove a lot of your code. In fact, the DefaultHttpClient should now work.

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

You no longer need the trusted key store, because the 3rd party will be your trusted key store now. DefaultHttpClient should do this automatically.

Comment: Right for sure, my question is for the testers - would the original code posted accept the trusted cert without any modifications, given that it is still being initialized with the self-signed cert?

Comment: Ah I seen, then I am not sure. Your cert will not be in myTrustedStore. It may default to external stores if it is not in the trusted store, but I am unsure.

As @GaborSch says below, if problems arise, add it to your trusted keystore for a temp fix.

Comment: You're right, but probably on test/staging/UAT instances they still need the old code...

Comment: @GaborSch, yeah for staging instances they'd still need the old code, but you're saying for production, the clients could leave their code the way it is and they wouldn't have any trouble with the trusted cert?